# how to make JavaFx2 application to .exe

Tags: javafx-2

is there a easy way to packing the Javafx2 application to a .exe file, within the JRE and Javafx runtime be pointed out and they can be all packed together as to public the software normally like oter windows application.

Comment: Are you seeking [self-contained application packaging](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) or something else?

Comment: yeah , i've read this before, but i work on Eclipse and just confused if necessary to write something in build.xml by hand , and write JavaFX Packager Command. and i just want to find is there any automatic tool to do these things. thank you.